# How to load javascript file from rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a plugin which is suppose to expose a javascript file, but I can't get it to load in my rails 5 application.

In my gem, I've tried adding my javascript file called `my_gem.js` to

- `vendor/assets/javascripts`
- `app/assets/javascripts`
- `lib/<gem-name>/assets/javascripts`

But none of them work. I just get this error message when loading the file in my `application.js`

```
couldn't find file 'my_gem' with type 'application/javascript'
```

This is how I load my plugin/gem in to my rails project

```
gem "my-gem", path: "~/projects/my-gem"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've [created a gem which utilizes assets before](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/exception_handler/error.css.erb).

You'll want to create an `app/assets/javascripts/my_gem` folder in your gem directory tree, where you'll put your `my_gem.js` file.

Most importantly, [you need to add this file to the asset path](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler/blob/master/lib/exception_handler.rb#L39) (we use an engine):

```
#lib/my_gem.rb
module MyGem
   class Gem < Rails::Engine
      config.assets.precompile += %w(my_gem/my_gem.js) 
   end
end
```

This will either allow the file to be used standalone, or as part of your app:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require my_gem/my_gem
```

Comment: Thanks! Almost correct. Adding `config.assets.precompile += %w(gem/file.js)` to the `engine.rb` exposes the `file.js` file meaning that `//= require file` should used, not `//= require gem/file`.

Answer (score 1):

You must tell Rails to compile my_gem.js. You can do this in an initializer, application.rb, or environment file.

```
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["my_gem.js"]
```

I'd recommend keeping the source file at `~/projects/my-gem/app/assets/javascripts/my_gem.js`

Comment: I upvoted although the above code needs to be in the gem, not the app ;)

Comment: An initializer can be in the gem

Comment: Yes of course; I thought your answer was ambiguous on the point though

Comment: Here is information about adding an initializer in your gem (assuming it is a Rails Engine) [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#separate-assets-precompiling)

Comment: ah, OK. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: No, this wont work as the gem as to expose/export the `my_gem.js` file, not the rails app using the gem. I wont downvote, but I suggest you remove this answer as the above answer is the correct one.